# How do I read an image file using Python?

Tags: python, image, file

How do I read an image file and decode it using Python?

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "read", what is your purpose?

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "decode", what do you want to do with the resulting image?

Comment: Install [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0).

Comment: You can `read` as binary, aka using the `rb` flags. in order to transmit the raw image data to another program via python. Python itself would need an image viewer to present that data as visual non-binary content.

Answer (score 53):

The word "read" is vague, but here is an example which reads a jpeg file using the Image class, and prints information about it.

```
from PIL import Image
jpgfile = Image.open("picture.jpg")

print(jpgfile.bits, jpgfile.size, jpgfile.format)
```

Comment: I want to read the jpg/png image & decode it .

Comment: If I run that code in the same directory as a file named "picture.jpg", I get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 2, in <module> import Image ImportError: No module named Image`. The os, sys imports are extraneous; you probably meant `from PIL import Image`, which requires running `easy_install PIL`, or if you're not feeling lucky (PIL requires a substantial amount of luck to install), `easy_install pillow`.

Comment: What's the `import os,sys` used for?

Comment: I think it should be image, not Image,