# why do I have a traceback with Image class?

Tags: python, image, file, class, traceback

I wrote this code:

```
import Image
im = raw_input("Insert Image file: ")
handle = Image.open(im)

print handle.size
```

to read an `Image` file and print its size, but when I run this code I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Image
```

P.S - I wrote the program in mac os x if it matters

Comment: What is `Image`? Have you defined it yourself? Is it a library? Are you sure you've installed it?

Comment: The last lines of the traceback are important.  They tell us what type of exception was raised (it's probably an `ImportError` though).  Could you include them please?

Comment: @iCodez oops, didn't notice I didn't add the last line:
ImportError: No module named Image

Comment: @Ffisegydd I read here: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

that there's an existing class named Image, so I used it..

Comment: That tutorial is 9 years old I think. I think what you're after is PIL.

Comment: @Ffisegydd I took a look at this question as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735553/how-do-i-read-an-image-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to install [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or [Pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/). Here is the [installation guide](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation) which can be summarized as:

1. Install [Brew](http://brew.sh/):

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. Install some dependencies for Pillow:

   ```
   brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
   ```
3. Install Pillow:

   ```
   pip install Pillow
   ```

And change:

```
import Image
```

To:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name your file `image.py`, and then try to import `Image` there is a high risk that Python tries to import your own file and that all that ends in a stack overflow (the bad event, not the nice site).

**NEVER give you files names that exists in Standard Python Library**