# Python on Mac: Image module cannot be installed

Tags: python, image, macos, package

I'm using Mac and trying to install the Image package for loading images (example: [How do I read an image file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735553/how-do-i-read-an-image-file-using-python)).

I'm using anaconda and PyCharm. The python version is 2.7.10.

If I try: `pip install Image`, it shows:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Image in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pillow in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Image)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Image)
```

But when I load it, it says "no module named Image".

I tried to install from PyCharm as well, but I cannot find `Image` from the package search (I can find "image" but seems to be a different one).

Comment: Not sure on this, but would "from PIL import Image" give you what you are looking for?

Comment: @J.Corson: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Python Imaging Library (PIL).  Given that you are using conda:

```
$ conda install pil
```

Then, from python:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I tried to import PIL and it was working before so I assumed I have PIL, but seems like the one I had was just a skeleton.

Comment: perhaps you imported it into a different environment?

Answer (score 1):

Would this give you what you want:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: this does not. The other solution is the correct one.