# How can I use Python to locate two files with identical names and check if they're equal?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, compare, hashcode

Summary:  How can I use Python to locate two files with identical names (in known locations) and see if they are identical using hash.

I currently have two folders, *Folder1* and *Folder2*.  I am trying to figure out how I can have Python **move file by file through *Folder1***.  For each file (which is a .jpg image), I would like to **use hash to get a unique integer for the image and copy the file name to a string**.  From this string, I plan to find the potential identical copy of that image in *Folder2* and then use hash to see if they are identical.

I am new to Python and this is my first post on Stack Overflow.  If there is any information I should include or area where I was unclear, please let me know and I will respond as soon as possible.  Thanks, and thank you to Ares for recommending the use of hash.

Comment: Try using Pillow. https://python-pillow.org/

Comment: Better compare  hashes (`sha` or `md5` or maybe perceptual hashes) of files instead of file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing file size really isn't enough, is it? You could easily have two files, a.jpg in folder A and a.jpg in folder B. They are both exactly 16 kb, except that one is a picture of a dog and one is a picture of a cat.

What may be valuable is to `hash` every image in the list. In Python, you can take anything - numbers, strings, images, etc - and call `hash()` on it.

A hash is a numeric representation of a specific set of data. Barring some rare exceptions, hashes are *exactly* unique to that data. No other sets of data, except those that are exactly the same, will have that hash.

Some examples:

`> hash('test')`

will output

`2314058222102390712`

`> hash('Test')`

`-1504849438355502056`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735553/how-do-i-read-an-image-file-using-python) describes how to load an image in Python. Then, just call `hash` on each image. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585730/what-does-hash-do-in-python) describes what a hash is if I was unclear.